# change won't work on mobile device

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I'm having an issue with this script:

```
$("#typecar").change(function(){            
            $.post("/ajaxtypecar?type=" +this.value, function( data ) {                 
                $('#makecar').html(data);           
            });         
        });
```

I'ts working fine on desktop.
When I'm trying on my iPhone nothing happens. The Change function isn't fired.

I've tried with an alert(); but it does't show up.

I've tried with on change also, but still the same.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Best regards 
/Palle

Comment: which kind of form field is "$("#typecar")"? I mean is it select, radio,checkbox etc.

Comment: Please provide more context, more code. Thx.

Comment: Hi Spatacus.

Thanks for chipping in.

It's a select box. And when I change the #typecar select I go grab the data using /ajaxtypecar?type= ... and putting the data in the next select box - #makecar.

And it's here the change doesn't fire.

I got this:
<select name="type" id="typecar">
<option value="1">cartype 1</option>
<option value="2">cartype 2</option>
</select>

<select name="make" id="makecar">

</select>